# How to write a generic iteration of a function using Java 8?

Tags: java, generics, java-8, functor

Please consider the following two functions:

```
public static <X, Y, U, V extends X> Function<U, Y> composite(
    Function<X, Y> first, Function<U, V> second)
{
    Objects.requireNonNull(first);
    Objects.requireNonNull(second);
    return (U arg) -> first.apply(second.apply(arg));
}

public static <X, Y extends X> Function<X, ?> iterate(Function<X, Y> function, int n)
{
    if (n < 0)
        return null;
    if (n == 0)
        return (X arg) -> arg;  
    Objects.requireNonNull(function);

    Function<X, Y> iteration = function;
    for (; n > 1; --n)
        iteration = composite(function, iteration);
    return iteration;
}
```

While `composite(first, second)` computes the [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition) of `first` and `second`, `iterate(function, n)` computes the `nth` [iterate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function) of `function`.

While the restriction `Y extends X` suffices for any `n > 0`, we've got some problem with `n == 0`. Mathematically, `iterate` should yield the identity function. However, therefore we would need `X extends Y`, i.e. `X == Y`, as well.

Please consider the following example

```
Function<Double, Double> nthSquareRoot = iterate(Math::sqrt, n);
```

This yields the error message:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Function<Double,capture#2-of ?> to Function<Double,Double>
```

What's the best option here? If `n == 1`, we could check if `X` is acceptable as `Y`. I would like to hear other options and some ideas how this check can be performed (as far as I know, there is no simple solution to check two generic parameters for equality).

Comment: Uhm... In Java 8 there is [`Function.compose()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#compose-java.util.function.Function-), why don't you use that?

Comment: @fge Thanks. You're right, I should use `Function.compose`. However, that doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
public static<X> UnaryOperator<X> iterate(UnaryOperator<X> f, int n) { ... }
```

If Y <: X, then a function from X to Y is also a function from X to X, and you should be able to do what you want.

Answer (score 5):

You need to change the type of your result to account for the wildcard:

```
Function<Double, ? extends Double> nthSquareRoot = iterate(Math::sqrt, 2);
```

and the signature of the `iterate` method to:

```
public static <X, Y extends X> Function<X, ? extends X> iterate(Function<X, Y> function, int n)
```

Example:

```
public static <X, Y extends X> Function<X, ? extends X> iterate(Function<X, Y> function, int n) {
  if (n < 0) return null;
  if (n == 0) return Function.identity();

  Function<X, Y> iteration = Objects.requireNonNull(function);
  for (; n > 1; --n) {
    iteration = composite(function, iteration);
  }
  return iteration;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  Function<Double, ? extends Double> nthSquareRoot = iterate(Math::sqrt, 2);
  System.out.println(nthSquareRoot.apply(81d));
}
```

prints 9 as expected.

---

Alternatively you can use a `UnaryOperator`:

```
public static <X> UnaryOperator<X> iterate(UnaryOperator<X> function, int n) {
  if (n < 0) return null;
  if (n == 0) return UnaryOperator.identity();

  UnaryOperator<X> iteration = Objects.requireNonNull(function);
  for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
    iteration = composite(function::apply, iteration::apply)::apply;
  }
  return iteration;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  UnaryOperator<Double> nthSquareRoot = iterate(Math::sqrt, 2);
  System.out.println(nthSquareRoot.apply(81d));
}
```